# Error when issuing ncks command, unexpected bytes object instead of string

Tags: netcdf, nco, pynco

When I issue an NCO call usign pynco for ncks I am getting an error, it looks like a bytes object is being sent instead of a string, resulting in this:

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 7864)
2018-02-05  11:30:53 INFO Start time:    2018-02-05 11:30:53.365789
Error in calling operator ncks with:
>>> C:/home/miniconda/pkgs/nco-4.7.1-vc14_0/Library/bin\ncks --dmn=lon,0,20,1 --output=C:/home/data/nclimgrid/work\nclimgrid_lowres_prcp_slice00.nc C:/home/data/nclimgrid/nclimgrid_lowres_prcp.nc <<<
Inputs: C:/home/data/nclimgrid/nclimgrid_lowres_prcp.nc
b''
2018-02-05  11:36:19 ERROR Failed to complete
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\git\process_grid\process_grid.py", line 949, in <module>
    options=slice_option)
  File "C:\home\miniconda\lib\site-packages\nco\nco.py", line 277, in get
    raise NCOException(**retvals)
nco.nco.NCOException: (returncode:3221225781) b''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\home\eclipse\neon\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_6.2.0.201711281614\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1621, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\home\eclipse\neon\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_6.2.0.201711281614\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1615, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\home\eclipse\neon\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_6.2.0.201711281614\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1022, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File
"C:\home\eclipse\neon\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_6.2.0.201711281614\pysrc\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\git\process_grid\process_grid.py", line 949, in <module>
    options=slice_option)
  File "C:\home\miniconda\lib\site-packages\nco\nco.py", line 277, in get
    raise NCOException(**retvals)
nco.nco.NCOException: (returncode:3221225781) b''
```

The code where this is happening:

```
# assume the same longitude slice specs across temperature, precipitation, and soils files
slice_option = ['--dmn=lon,{0},{1},1'.format(precip_files[i][1], precip_files[i][2])]

# use NCO to slice the specified longitude range from the files
slice_file_precip = precip_files[i][0]
nco.ncks(input=args.precip_file, 
         output=slice_file_precip, 
         options=slice_option)
```

I can debug into the pynco code and see that this is happening in the nco.__getattr__.get() function, when it gets in there the `cmd` list object passed to the ncks binary looks like this:

```
<class 'list'>: ['C:/home/miniconda/pkgs/nco-4.7.1-vc14_0/Library/bin\\ncks', 
                 '--dmn=lon,0,20,1', 
                 '--output=C:/home/data/nclimgrid/work\\nclimgrid_lowres_prcp_slice00.nc', 
                 'C:/home/data/nclimgrid/nclimgrid_lowres_prcp.nc']
```

The error message appears to show an empty second input, `b''`, maybe this is being inserted by mistake somehow, as there is no second input file?

Where are things going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to pyno appears correct.
 I am unable  to recreate your error on a Linux box. 
 And I don't have python on windows.

A couple of things you can try

1. Run the ncks command directly:

   **C:/home/miniconda/pkgs/nco-4.7.1-vc14_0/Library/bin\ncks --dmn=lon,0,20,1 --output=C:/home/data/nclimgrid/work\nclimgrid_lowres_prcp_slice00.nc C:/home/data/nclimgrid/nclimgrid_lowres_prcp.nc**
2. Try running the test modules in **pynco/tests** do this by running 
    the command 'py.test' in your pynco directory. You may have to install the python module 'pytest'

...Henry

Comment: 7 out of 22 of the pynco tests fail, thanks for pointing this out @Henry Fey, I will look into this further...